# What is the difference on const user-defined-conversions and non const?

Tags: c++

So, if I have:

```
class test
{
public:

    operator const int() {...}
    operator int() {...}

};
```

Why is this following then ambiguous?:

```
test a;
(const int) a;
```

Isn't it like an explicit cast that I want a `const int`?

I tested this also with class types (not built in types) instead of `int`, and it is still ambiguous, but why?

Would be very happy if someone could explain why.

Comment: Is there any point to conversion function to a `const`? The receiver will or will not be a `const` and I can't see it mattering at all.

Comment: Do you have a particular use case for this or is it out of curiosity? Part of what drove C++'s design was making it useful over "pure".

Comment: Thanks guys! It is mainly because of curiosity, would love to know why.

Comment: If return value is `const`, it cannot be modified. Most of time it's useful when a function returns `const pointer` or `const reference`. Not much difference when it's a integer.

Comment: It's ambiguous because the return type isn't part of the what determines whether a method gets called. So two methods with the same signature aside from the return type will be ambiguous. However a different signature like `operator const int() const {...}` will not be ambiguous.

Comment: @doug when you add the `const` keyword to the function you create a different signature because the hidden `this` parameter changes from non-const to const. You probably know that already but I thought it should be explained.

Answer (score 3):

These are ambiguous.

```
operator const int() {...}l
operator int() {...}l
```

It's ambiguous because the return type isn't part of the what determines whether a method gets called and conversion types ignore `const` so two methods with the same signature aside will be ambiguous. However a different signature like this

```
operator const int() const {...}
operator int() {...}
```

will not be ambiguous and can be used to distinguish calls between const and non const objects. Further, this also means that the first function will not alter the object's "state" so is useful for users of the class in that it tells them the operation will not alter the object (aside from `mutable` members which can sometimes be useful for caching state.)

Please note that @user4581301's comment that there is rarely a reason to declare the return type const. It's going to get the type assigned to whether const or not. But this doesn't apply to reference returns.

As other's have pointed out, Conversion operators, unlike other methods, include the conversion type. But const is ignored so the following would not be ambiguous:

```
operator double() {...}
operator int() {...}
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you so much!! Helped me a lot. 

Comment: Short question again:
What is actually the signature? Because what if i have a const int& and only a int&?

Comment: Conversion operators **are** distinguished by the return type. `operator int()` and `operator double()` are two different overloads, and `(double)a` would not be ambiguous. The problem in the question arises because the top-level `const` is ignored. Just like `void f(int){}` versus `void f(const int){}`, where the second is a redefinition (hence illegal), not an overload.

Comment: !!!! This was exactly the answer i needed, thank you very much! Makes sense if i look at this that way.

Comment: But thank you also doug! You both helped me a lot!

Comment: @PeteBecker
So there is one last thing which sounds very silly but: Why can the language itself convert without problems to (int) and (const int), and so on, but we can't? Shouldnt it be that therefore we also should?

Comment: @Avva.  The conversion operators you used returns values that don't have a memory location yet and has no address. With no address you can't modify it. You can use it as part of another calculation. So whether it's a const or not makes no difference. But you can assign either to the name of an `int` or use it to initialize a `const int`  You can't assign it to the name of an already existing `const int`

Comment: @Avva -- it's not silly; the rules could have been written to allow that difference, but there's very little, if anything, that you could do with that. More generally, it's the issue I mentioned earlier: `f(int)` versus `f(const int)`. When you say `f(x)`, the value of `x` is being copied, so it doesn't matter whether it's `const` or not.

Comment: Thank you very much!